# Subdivide a Modulo function - 16 bit but can only do 8 bits at a time

Tags: math, binary, mips, modulo

I'm trying to find the modulo of two 16 bit binary numbers. I can only do 8 bits at a time. Is there a way to divide a 16 bit modulo equation in multiple 8 bit equations?

if so,

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an 8-bit CPU, chances are that it can't do division or modulo operations natively (you might be lucky to have a multiplier!), so there is no point in trying to leverage the processor to break 16 bit operations in 8 bit operations. AFAIK, there is no way of doing it anyways. You'll need to do the division bit by bit.  (Most hardware implementations of division also do the division bit-by-bit, it's unavoidable. It is not like multiplication which can be done in parallel.).

I think you will need to implement the "Russian Peasant" method, mention here in this other stack overflow article:  [Fastest way to calculate a 128-bit integer modulo a 64-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566010/fastest-way-to-calculate-a-128-bit-integer-modulo-a-64-bit-integer?rq=1)

I've pasted the answer here:

To find the remainder, execute (in pseudo-code):

```
X = B;

while (X < A/2)
{
    X <<= 1;
}

while (A >= B)
{
    if (A >= X)
        A -= X;
    X >>= 1;
}
```

The modulus is left in A.