# Does anyone know a better way for modulo on bits?

Tags: c, math, biginteger, modulo

I have 2 big numbers, one about 4096 bits and the other 2048 bits, stored in a structure:

```
 typedef uint32_t word;
 typedef struct BigNumber {
     word words[128];
 } BigNumber;
```

I have to make the modulo of those and only way I can think to do it is subtract multiple times, but this take some time.

Does any one know a better way to do this?

Comment: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use MGP library , and their code is not really reusable for me

Comment: Is it about arbitrary number modulo or module with some power 2 number (set higher bits to zero)?

Comment: @grek40 arbitrary , it is no special rule except the length

Comment: @ZangMingJie: not really a duplicate. This is a 128*32 = 4096 bit integer. But the same principles apply, indeed.

Comment: The question is unclear. So one number is type `BigNumber`, the "one about 4096 bits".  The other number " the other 2048 bits" is of what type?  Is the modulo " one about 4096 bits" modulo "the other 2048 bits" or visa-versa?  Posting what you have done rather than musing "only way I can think to do it is subtract multiple times" would add clarity.  Detailing about timing goals would help too.

Comment: @chux number A is 4096 bits (type BigNumber) , number B 2048 bits (type is also BigNumber to be easier at operations ["2048Xzero " and the actual number]) , I need to calculate A%B , what I already made is :  "while (A>B)   A=A-B "  , and I am looking for something like a scheme to increase my eficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code based on [@caf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566570/2410359) with my correction.  Leave OP to code the 4 helper functions.

```
void BigNumber_Shift_Right(BigNumber *x);
void BigNumber_Shift_Left(BigNumber *x);
int BigNumber_Compare(const BigNumber *a, const BigNumber *b);
void BigNumber_SubtractEqual(BigNumber *a, const BigNumber *b);

void BigNumber_ModHalfSizeEqual(BigNumber *A, const BigNumber *B) {
  BigNumber X = *B;
  BigNumber AHalf = *A;
  BigNumber_Shift_Right(&AHalf);

  while (BigNumber_Compare(&X, &AHalf) <= 0) {
    BigNumber_Shift_Left(&X);
  }

  while (BigNumber_Compare(A, B) >= 0) {
    if (BigNumber_Compare(A, &X) >= 0) {
      BigNumber_SubtractEqual(A, &X); 
    }
    BigNumber_Shift_Right(&X);
  }

  // mod is in A
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To calculate m % n:

```
modulus(m, n) {
  if (m < n) return m
  elif (m < (n<<1)) return m - n
  else return modulus((modulus(m>>1, n)<<1 + m&1), n)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is  a model for repetitive subtraction , I was curious if there are any special rules for increasing the efficiency of the algorithm

Comment: @PopoviciSebi this uses the special rules, it's not just "keep subtracting until the heat-death of the universe". Note the shifts.

Comment: @Harold can you please explain me a little bit the concept I am not sure I understand the math behind that

Comment: I found a better implementation and explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566010/fastest-way-to-calculate-a-128-bit-integer-modulo-a-64-bit-integer, I'll mark the question as duplicated

Comment: ok Thank you , I think this might work

Comment: @chux `+ m&1` will fix that

Comment: Tried further testing, code looks good except when `n > MAX_VALUE/2`, then `(n<<1)` is a problem.  Could use `elif (m >> 1 < n) return m - n;` to fix.

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2566570/2410359 also has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide a by b and get a whole number x. Now subtract x from a and you get the modulus. With arbitrary divisors you won't get around the division. For big divisors this might be faster than multiple subtractions, but divisions are still expensive.

You may also have to implement the divison algorithm manually for such big numbers. There is one out there, which results in qoutient and remainder (modulus) at the same time, but i cannot recall its name now.

Comment: Sorry , I tried this to , but is almost the same time , and takes more memory