# Is there sth. similar to _udiv128 for gcc?

Tags: gcc, g++

Is there sth. similar to MSVC's _udiv128() for gcc ? If I use __int128 variable as the dividend and have an normal "/"-divide the compiler doesn't know that the result fits in an unsigned long long and calls an external function which does the subtract and shift division manually. So it would be nice to have sth. like _udiv128().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2566010/634919 suggests no.

Comment: @NateEldredge Im asking for code where the result and the remainder fit in 64 bit each.

Answer (score 1):

For a x86_64-only solution, you could provide an inline-assembly function:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t udiv128_64(__uint128_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    asm inline("divq %1\n\t"
        : "+A"(a)
        : "r"(b)
        : "cc");
    return a;
}
```

From your comment, I assume it is ok for you, if the code crashes when the result does not fit into 64bits.
Godbolt demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qTbxx7vhT

Another disadvantage with inline-assembly is that it won't be optimized away if the result could be computed at compile-time.

gcc does a lot of unnecessary register movements, for the function alone, but these should usually be optimized away, if the function is inlined.